# How to convert static site to dynamic site

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, gatsby, static-site

I recently built a React site using the static site generator Gatsby.JS and was wondering if there was an easy way for me to convert it to a dynamic site? I'm not sure what's best, extract the Gatsby, deploy as dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can continue to use Gatsby and still make the site dynamic. It depends what you mean by "dynamic" exactly.

When a user visits your site, Gatsby will boot React as normal. So if you want to fetch some data, show the user something special if they have already logged in, etc, this is all possible.

There are some special rules to consider with Gatsby. Make sure that the first version of your page is the same as what Gatsby sees. So you can add logic into `onComponentDidMount` to change the UI only after React has loaded.

Otherwise, if you want to simply remove Gatsby altogether, you take your existing React components and move them all to a new project. I'd recommend starting with a blank `create-react-app` project and copying the components over. The refactoring required should be minimal.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there anything special I should do to handle the plugins I used for the original Gatsby app? Just install them with my new react app?

Comment: It really depends. Some of the plugins (like image processing or source plugins) will be highly Gatsby specific and won't really apply to a "generic" react app. Plugins like Helmet can be replaced with their normal react versions.